# Is there a programmatically way for Excels "Protect Workbook"?

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm moving some legacy code using Office Interop libraries to epplus, one thing I can't figure out is how to set a Workbook to ask the user on open the file to open it read only. Like if the user clicks on File -> Info -> Protect Workbook -> Always Open Read-Only

I've tried to set the DocSecurity property stated here (https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/OOXML.html), but to no success. `excelWorkBook.Properties.SetExtendedPropertyValue("DocSecurity", "2");`

I also tried to add the following node to the workbookxml `<fileSharing readOnlyRecommended="1"/>`

I even tried to compare the unzipped excel files protected, non protected, but there were too many changes.

Comment: Workbooks have a protect method.. I would expect it to be protected with no password or something

Comment: Appologies, but where is a protect method on the workbook? I only see the "Protection" property, worksheets do have more protection/locking methods but that is not the same functionality.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.protect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vsto-2017#Microsoft_Office_Tools_Excel_Workbook_Protect_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_

Comment: Hi, sorry for getting back late. This is exactly what I do not want to do, as the text and the tags say I want to do this with epplus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done but it is not really straightforward.  Setting `DocSecurity` can be done by generating the `Workbook.Properties` object.  But that is only half of it.  You also need to set the flag inside the `Workbook` itself which can only be done via XML manipulation.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DocSecurity_Test()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335624/is-there-a-programmatically-way-for-excels-protect-workbook
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\DocSecurity_Test.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        //Create a simple workbook
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Test";

        //Extended properties is a singleton so reference it to generate the app.xml file
        //needed and add the security setting
        var extProps = workbook.Properties;
        extProps.SetExtendedPropertyValue("DocSecurity", "2");

        //Also need to tell the workbook itself but can only do it via XML
        var xml  = workbook.WorkbookXml;
        var att = xml.CreateAttribute("readOnlyRecommended");
        att.Value = "1";

        const string mainNs = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main";
        var fileSharing = xml.CreateElement("fileSharing", mainNs);
        fileSharing.Attributes.Append(att);

        //Element must be at the beginning of the tree
        xml.DocumentElement.PrependChild(fileSharing);
        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Which will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, exactly what I was looking forward to! Thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: One small addition, fileSharing has to be the 2nd node after fileVersion

`var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
                        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("xls", mainNs);

                        var fileVersionNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//xls:fileVersion", namespaceManager);

                        //Element must be after fileVersion
                        xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(fileSharing, fileVersionNode);`